# How to pass ssh arguments into a ProxyCommand

Tags: ssh

I have been struggling with setting up a ProxyCommand to ssh through multiple hops. The issue I am having is integrating arguments in my normal ssh statement into the config file. I want to connect to **IP2** via **IP1**. My username is greg and I am connecting using rsa. This is the one liner that will connect me:

```
  ssh -A -t -p 22 -i ~/.ssh/private_key greg@IP1 ssh -A -t greg@IP2
```

I have tried a bunch of different config set ups and currently I am using:

```
Host ezConnect
ProxyCommand ssh %h nc IP2 22
HostKeyAlias IP2
HostName IP1
User greg
```

I know the issue is that it does not include the arguments I need, but wherever I try to put them it seems to break.

The reason I'm doing this is because I need to use a db GUI (navicat) to connect through a gateway server and the UI doesn't support a strait up ssh command.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out so here is the correct config fie:

```
Host ezCon
    Hostname **IP2**
    User greg
    ProxyCommand ssh -l greg -p 22 -i ~/.ssh/private_key **IP1** -W %h:%p
```